# how can I use linq to return another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable and I want to use a linq statement to serialize each object in the IEnumerable and return another list. Here's my foreach I have:

```
List<EventData> payloads = new List<EventData>();

foreach (var request in requestList)
{
   string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

   EventData data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
   payloads.Add(data);
}
```

I was attempting to do a Select statement like this:

```
requestList.Select(request => { JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request); });
```

Error message is :

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable, Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: I get an error saying: `The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Comment: `var list = requestList.Select(request => new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)))).ToList();`

Comment: The problem is that the curly brackets mean you have a method body, but you're not returning anything from it.

Comment: What type is `requestList`?

Comment: Side note: typically variables of a collection type are named with the plural of the type they contain, so if `requestList` is a `List<Request>`, it would simply be named `requests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original code was that there is a method body defined with curly braces, but it doesn't return anything. To fix this, you can simply take your existing code and put it into the select statement, but add a `return` statement from the block:

```
List<EventData> payloads = requestList.Select(request => 
{ 
    string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    EventData data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
    return data;
}).ToList();
```

Or you could do the same thing without the method body approach, but this sometimes makes the code a little harder to read and debug, since you're doing everything in one line:

```
List<EventData> payloads = requestList
    .Select(request => 
        new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request))))
    .ToList();
```